# Cmake can't find files even with path provided when configuring

Tags: linux, installation, cmake, cmake-gui

I am trying to build OpenSim from source code using the CMake GUI as per these instructions (Linux) : https://github.com/simbody/simbody
I have found several problems in step 3 of this process, at first the program didn't seem to find Simbody even though I have that installed and have the path to the code specified like so:
[image]

After I tried to configure the code a few times a new error popped up:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:575 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "BTK" with any of
the following names:

BTKConfig.cmake
btk-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "BTK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "BTK_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "BTK" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I tried to solve this by specifying the path to the required files (I do have them) in the 'Value' field, but as soon as I hit 'configure' the path is gone and it reverts back to the 'BTK_DIR-NOTFOUND' you see in the picture.

I have closely followed all the instructions listed through the Opensim website but still nothing is working as it should, any help would be immensely appreciated

Comment: So, what **exact absolute path** of file `BTKConfig.cmake` (or `btk-config.cmake`), and what **exact value** you entered for `BTK_DIR` variable? I would repeat the error message about this variable: 'set "BTK_DIR"
to a **directory** containing one of the above files.'

Comment: Did you try *deleting* your CMake cache and running the `cmake`  command line from your build directory from scratch. When doing this, provide the `BTK_DIR` variable as an argument: `cmake -DBTK_DIR=/path/to/your/btk/configs ..`

Comment: Tsyvarev That's exactly what I did, but cmake still says it can't find the file :(. @squareskittles Any idea how I delete this cache? I've tried your command in the terminal after closing the cmake window and I get an error that the given directory doesn't exist..it absolutely does as I'm in it right now looking at the configuration file it wants from me

Comment: The CMake GUI provides an option for deleting the CMake cache.